# How to get the similarity between two strings?

Tags: php, security

I want to create a function which will alert a user if there is a multiple brute force attempt on an account. The function will alert the user if there is more than 75% string match. I have performed this:

```
function Password_Match ($String, $Stored_Password){
    $New_String = str_split($String);
    $New_Stored_Password = str_split($Stored_Password);
        $Match = 0;
    foreach ($New_String AS $Value){
        if (in_array($Value,$New_Stored_Password)){
            $Match++;
        }
    }
    return $Match;

}

$String = "Test";
$Pass = "Tesst";
echo Password_Match($String,$Pass);
```

This returns 4, but there is obviously a flaw within my code that I can't figure out a solution. Assitance would be brilliant.

Comment: You are talking about "string match" as if there were a universal definition for it.

Comment: [php similar-text](http://php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php)

Comment: This function simply determines whether the characters of one string are present in another string. However, it doesn’t care neither about the position nor about repetitions. So `aaaaaa` and `abcdef` is said to have 6 matches as each `a` in `aaaaaa` is present in `abcdef`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't be doing this in the first place.

Brute force attacks should simply be prevented by imposing hourly / daily limits on failed attempts. What does the user care how close the hackers were to guessing the password?

Also, much more importantly, **you shouldn't be storing the user's password in clear text in the first place**. That's a far more serious security problem than you can make up by telling the user about cracking attempts.

See these questions for some in-depth discussion on how to properly store passwords:

- [Secure hash and salt for PHP passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401656/secure-hash-and-salt-for-php-passwords)
- [The definitive guide to form-based website authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549/the-definitive-guide-to-forms-based-website-authentication)

Comment: -1 for putting a comment as an answer but +1 for pointing out the obvious "you shouldn't be storing the user's password stored in clear text "

Comment: yes i agree @popnoodles. i do like comment by OP "there is obviously a flaw within my code"

Answer (score 1):

What your trying to do is measure `edit distance` between two strings. PHP has a built in function to accomplish this.

```
int levenshtein ( string $str1 , string $str2 )
```

to wrap up the answer

```
$x = levenshtein ($str1 ,$str2);

$ratio = $x / strlen($str1); //or 2 

if ($ratio > 0.75) { //case match } 
else { //case miss match}
```

Answer (score 0):

Passwords should be encrypted using a one way encryption, they should not be stored in the database as plain text. BUT if you really want to approach this way.. Try something like this:

```
function Password_Match ($String, $Stored_Password){
    similar_text($String,$Stored_Password,$Percentage);
    if ($Percentage > 75){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```